# How can I convert string date to NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to convert `2016-03-09 00:00:00` to `09/03/2016`

I am try below code but print `nil` value

```
var date: [String] = ["2016-03-09 00:00:00", "2016-03-20 00:00:00"]

for i in date {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
    let showDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(i)
    print(showDate)
}
```

above code print `nil`
pls help me how to print date `dd/MM/YYYY` format in swift

Comment: Use `"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` instead, and then change it to `09/03/2016`.

Comment: @Eendje i need to print only date ( "dd/MM/YYYY") from array

Comment: date array value come from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your date format is wrong. change "dd/MM/YYYY" with "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:s" and try ...

> You have a date like "2016-03-09 00:00:00" .. so format should be "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:s"

```
for i in date {
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:s"
  if let showDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(i){
     print("Date with Time: \(showDate)")
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
     let resultString         = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(showDate)
     print("final result: \(resultString)")  
  }
}
```

**Result:-**

```
Date with Time: 2016-03-09 00:00:00 +0000
final result: 2016-03-09 
Date with Time: 2016-03-20 00:00:00 +0000
final result: 2016-03-20
```

Comment: I only need to print date only, time is not reqired

Answer (score 1):

You should first create a dateformatter to handle the type. Then sort your format such as:

```
let date: [String] = ["2016-03-09 00:00:00", "2016-03-20 00:00:00"]

for i in date {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:s"
    let showDate:NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(i)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
    let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(showDate!)
    print(date)

}
```

Comment: Why create a new date formatter for each pass through the loop, AND reconfigure it with a different format each time? See my answer, where I create 2 date formatters once, outside the loop. MUCH more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reconfiguring a single date formatter on each pass through the loop in @ElCaptain's answer I would suggest creating 2 outside the loop: an input date formatter for converting from "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:s" date strings to NSDates, and an output formatter for converting from NSDates to "YYYY-MM-dd" format.

```
let inputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:s"
let outputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
ourputFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

for i in date {
  if let showDate = inputFormatter.dateFromString(i) {
     print("Date with Time: \(showDate)")
     let resultString = outputFormatter.stringFromDate(showDate)
     print("final result: \(resultString)")  
  }
}
```

Comment: you are right if date array size 10 or more than every time create new variable for NSDateFormatter.

Comment: thank you for ans, In my date array contain 1000 date or more

Comment: If you are processing 1000+ dates then you very definitely want to set up 2 date formatters outside the loop and use those. El Captain's code would create a new date formatter and reconfigure it for each pass through the loop, which is slow and inefficient.